# Building cross platform shared libraries from C# code

Tags: c#, android, linux, cross-platform

I have a scenario where a software system has been developed using C#. Algorithms within that system have been implemented as shared libraries (but also written in C#) in an attempt to make the system more modular, i.e. functionality can be added/removed by adding/removing the various .dlls.

I am interested in how easily the existing code-base could be re-used on non-windows platforms. Would it be possible to:

a) build the whole system such that it could run on a non-windows platform?

b) build the whole system such that it could run on an android device?

c) cross-build the component C# shared libraries such that they could run on a linux based platform (or as android native libs via the NDK)?

As well as being interested in whether these options are *possible*, I'm also interested in whether they are *sensible*, i.e. does it make sense to reuse what we've got or really should you just start from scratch?

Comment: If i understood correctly you are trying to use the C# code in the android NDK and generic Linux shared objects right?

Comment: i am wondering if it is possible to reuse the code in this way, yes..

Comment: NDK can hardly work with C#, with C, better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to port a C# code into NDK. Since the Android NDK supports C++ as native language and (Much like Java's JNI) but i am not aware of C# in NDK/JNI you may try [this](https://cscpp.codeplex.com/) which may help you to port the C# code into C++ (I haven't tried/used) if it seems to be feasible/possible to you if the code ported successfully then you can try with NDK/JNI. For the linux partif you successfully ported these code to android using NDK, It won't be a big deal since the android's kernel is just a fork of linux.